# Is there a Rails gem that allows a user to send HTML emails via the Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-email, rich-text-editor

We want to send emails to registered users on our site.

As of now we programmatically create emails and send them like that, too.

What we would like would be a way that a moderator of the site can create an HTML email using a rich text editor on the Rails app, select users from the database, and send it out.

In essence it would behave a little like a web mailer, like gmail. But: mails would be composed as templates and could use some ERB, so they can be re-used to email users, etc.

A sample application could be a newsletter or a broadcast search that is sent to all, or only some users.

Is there a gem that does this?

If no, how would you set this up?

Comment: just added some more what I want to achieve with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, sorry -- I didn't understand the question. I don't think there's a gem for your case, because it's a very specific use case.

What I would recommend is storing a blob of ERB text in the database for the email template. Then you can use something like this to render the email:

```
require 'erb'
name = user.name
email_html = ERB.new(email.template).result(binding)
```

See the [ERB Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a gem that does this specifically, but you can check out [action mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), which is included in Rails by default.

It's very good for sending out templated emails (account confirmation, etc). You create a view, and it renders the content of that view (with ERB) into the body of the email.

You might be able to use this for more customization, but I haven't played around with it too much.

Another option, if you're programmatically sending mail through the UNIX `mail` command, is to specify the content type as HTML. The command I use is:

`mail -a 'Content-type: text/html' -s 'Subject' to_address@example.com < file_containing_message.html`

Comment: dear graysonwright, this isn't really helping. Of course I would use something like action mailer to send the mails. 
My focus actually lies on composing the emails as templates, without needing access to the rails app itself: a moderater user could just create new emails, which can contain ERB, and which can be sent to some or all users in the system. In a way it would behave like gmail, just for my web app.